# Made easy prime app vs Moto G71 5G. Play Error android.media.Media Drm$Media DrmState Exception: Failed to handle key response: General DRM error

Tags: php, android

Made easy prime app from play Store is playing well with every other phone but on Moto G71 5G  Live lectures and recorded videos are freezing and sound are cracking.
And after playing 5 to 10min it is showing following message.

Play Error

android.media.Media Drm$Media DrmState Exception: Failed to handle key response: General DRM error

Comment: I am attaching link of application

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.madeeasy.prime.app

Video proof of freezing
https://youtu.be/6o8DAfwGXMQ
https://youtu.be/gO6-m9IK4o0
https://youtu.be/LK4yo0AVLag
https://youtu.be/xPnAnzeggZg
https://youtu.be/jJUx8sdfJbo

Video on other mobile on7prime there is no lag or freezing

https://youtu.be/T0bq84Z_FAw

Comment: Please help me solve this problem